# Mysql query returns duplicate rows when joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a table that stores user_avatar filepath :

```
id | userid | file         | last_update |
1  | 23     | myphoto.png  | x_timestamp |
2  | 23     | myphoto2.png | x_timestamp |
3  | 25     | myavatar.png | x_timestamp |
```

I have a table that returns user_score :

```
id | gamerid | score | last_update |
1  | 23      | 44    | x_timestamp |
2  | 25      | 99    | x_timestamp |
```

This is the query I use to display user scores with their avatar

```
SELECT * FROM user_score us LEFT JOIN user_avatar ua ON us.gamerid=ua.userid
```

Above query will return 2 duplicate rows for user 23 because he as downloaded 2 different photos in the user_avatar table. Right now it outputs like this:

```
GAMER SCORES RESULTS
myphoto.png  | 44
myphoto2.png | 44
myavatar.png | 99
```

In reality, only one row should be returned for each user and the last avatar downloaded should be used as primary avatar. How can I fix this?

Comment: How to define what avatar record is "last"?

Comment: Would it be better to have the avatar id on the user table.  Then they can upload several avatars and select which one they want to have shown.

Comment: In user_avatar table you can kept feild as created_at through which we can extract your desired data.

Comment: if a user has multiple file name then which one you need

Comment: @Fahmi  Op said `last avatar downloaded should be used as primary avatar`

Comment: @Akina : I have updated my question. I forgot to add the last column. I apologize for that.

Comment: You don't clearly explain what you want, you just give a paritial difference from an example of what you don't want. Please in code questions give a [mre]--including a clear specification. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT * FROM user_score us LEFT JOIN user_avatar ua ON us.gamerid=ua.userid 
and ua.last_update = 
   (select max(last_update) from user_avatar ua1 where ua.userid=ua1.userid)
```

Comment: Very elegant sir.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the value for the most recent avatar  .. probably related  ton the max id for user_id

```
SELECT ua.*, us.* 
FROM user_score us 
INNER JOIN  (
  select user_id, max(id) max_id 
  from user_avatar
) t on t.user_id = us.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_avatar ua 
  ON us.gamerid=ua.u serid 
    AND t.max_id  = ua.id
```

In reality, the last avatar downloa